# Persist Stable ID across multiple subdomains

Tags: statsig

We faced a problem with losing StableID while redirecting between subDomains. If it saves only in localStorage so in this case it's not gonna work.

What can we do to maintain our StableID during the subDomains redirects? If there is no any decision - do we have a method to change StableID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statsig uses localstorage to persist user id, so this is not technically possible because of how local storage is tied to a specific subdomain.

However if you want to persist a user across your own subdomains, you could use a cookie to preserve user-id and then pass that user-id to Statsig.